# Repute vs. Impute?

Tags: differences, vocabulary

In our vocabulary book, the definition for impute is:

> *tr. v.*: To attribute or ascribe a quality, especially a fault, to a person

The definition of repute is:

> *tr. v.*: To assign a reputation to

I don't see the difference between these two words - they both are used to assign a reputation/quality to a person/thing.

For example, would it be correct to say either:

> Bob is *imputed* to procrastinate.

or:

> Bob is *reputed* to procrastinate.

What is the difference? (examples, please?)

Comment: I'm sorry that this was not a good question, and was downvoted. Why? Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: This is, in fact, an excellent question.  You are the victim of a driveby downvoter, a plague on this site.  Ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Impute" means to ascribe some characteristic to.  This can be a cause attributed to an action:

> I **impute** your tardiness to an unspoken wish to be rid of my company.

or an attribution of some quality:

> People **impute** wisdom to owls, but they're not any smarter than sparrows.

The *OED* notes that at one time, "repute" had a meaning synonymous with "impute," but that's now considered obsolete.  "Repute" now means consider, as in this oath that clerics of the Church of England take:

> And in any case any oath made .. by me ... to the Bishop of Rome [the
>   Pope] I **repute** the same at vain and annhilate.

We hear this more in the passive voice:

> He **is reputed** to be a ladies' man.

If enough people impute some characteristic to you, the more likely you will be reputed to have that characterization.

Comment: That's a great description. To recap, impute is to associate a characteristic to, but repute is about an already associated characteristic (something already considered).

Comment: @jlam55555 Yes, that's why if you're reputed to be X, you have a reputation for X.

Comment: Full marks for discovering that gem from the Anglican oath!

Answer (score 0):

I think the last answer was correct however the word repute in the anglican oath is, I believe, short for repudiate not repute. That being said I believe the distinction is correct.